# Image width binding in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I have a very basic app that I believe should change the width of an image, but it does nothing... can anyone tell me why, when I click on the image, nothing happens to the image?

*(note, the image itself doesnt really matter, Im just trying to figure out how to shrink and grow and image in JavaFX)*

```
import javafx.application.Frame;
import javafx.application.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.input.MouseEvent;

var w:Number = 250;

Frame {
    title: "Image View Sample"
    width: 500
    height: 500
    closeAction: function() { 
        java.lang.System.exit( 0 ); 
    }
    visible: true

    stage: Stage {
        content: [
            ImageView {
                x: 200;
                y: 200;
                image: Image {
                    url: "{__DIR__}/c1.png"
                    width: bind w;
                }

                onMouseClicked: function( e: MouseEvent ):Void {
                    w = 100;
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind scale attributes:

```
import java.lang.System;
import javafx.application.Frame;
import javafx.application.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.input.MouseEvent;

var w:Number = 1;

Frame {
    title: "Image View Sample"
    width: 500
    height: 500
    closeAction: function() { 
        java.lang.System.exit( 0 ); 
    }
    visible: true

    stage: Stage {
        content: [
            ImageView {
                x: 200
                y: 200
                anchorX:200 
                anchorY:200
                scaleX:bind w
                scaleY:bind w
                image: Image {
                    url: "{__DIR__}/time.png"                    
                }

                onMouseClicked: function( e: MouseEvent ):Void {
                    w += 0.1;                    
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply, sorry for the delay getting back to you, but it turns out that all you need to do is to bind the image itself:

```
image: bind Image {
    url: "{__DIR__}/time.png"
    width: w;
}
```

And that seems to do the trick, which personally I find a bit missleading, but hey, it works